# Metasploit Framework: Remove Vulnerabilities from Database?

Tags: databases, metasploit

Is it possible to remove the vulnerabilities in Metasploit Frameworks's database that I have imported from Nexpose and Nessus? I want to remove the vulnerabilities from the database while keeping the services in the database.

I have tried using the command `msf > hosts -d 192.168.68.129 -c vulns` or `msf > hosts -c vulns -r 192.168.68.129`. Both of these commands results in the entire host being deleted from the database, not the vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to delete `vuln` objects from within `msfconsole`. The best way would be to drop into `irb` and delete them from there.

```
msf exploit(ms08_067_netapi) > irb
[*] Starting IRB shell...

Loaded ~/.irbrc
>> framework.db.vulns
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Mdm::Vuln id: 59, host_id: 320, service_id: nil, created_at: "2016-12-30 17:22:01", name: "MS08-067 Microsoft Server Service Relative Path St...", updated_at: "2016-12-30 17:22:01", info: "Exploited by exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi t...", exploited_at: "2016-12-30 17:22:01", vuln_detail_count: 0, vuln_attempt_count: 1, origin_id: nil, origin_type: nil>]>
>> framework.db.vulns.map(&:destroy)
=> [#<Mdm::Vuln id: 59, host_id: 320, service_id: nil, created_at: "2016-12-30 17:22:01", name: "MS08-067 Microsoft Server Service Relative Path St...", updated_at: "2016-12-30 17:22:01", info: "Exploited by exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi t...", exploited_at: "2016-12-30 17:22:01", vuln_detail_count: 0, vuln_attempt_count: 1, origin_id: nil, origin_type: nil>]
>> framework.db.vulns
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Doing it this way will also remove all the associations with hosts, so you won't have dangling references in the join table like you would if you just deleted them in `psql`.

Answer (score 1):

Metasploit use postgresql database. So in the worst of the cases, you can drop a sql shell into your database and try to find/delete the undesired rows by manual sql statements.

Anyway, if you want to remove some available exploit/s, is as simple as deleting it from the file system and then rebuilding the database cache in metasploit `db_rebuild_cache`. To locate your modules you can use `find` or `locate`commands. Depending of the distro, the files could be in different locations. In my Kali Linux, they are on `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules` and there are a lot of directories with exploits, payloads, etc.